# Как мне можно асинхронно улучшить приложение Golang?

Tags: golang

Хотел бы спросить насчет го с параллельной моделью. Я пытаюсь отправить множество `Get` запросов асинхронно на `localhost` при помощи `Golang (Goroutines)`, читал что асинхронность наивысшая и т.д. Пытался увеличить количество горутин в функции, вот код:

```
func main() {
    go Http()
}

host := "localhost:8080"

func Http() {
    for i := 0; i < 100 {
        go func() {

            for i := 0; i < 100 {
                req, err := http.Get(host)
                if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
                defer.Body.Close() 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но почему-то не дает такого сильного прироста как я ожидал, как можно увеличить количество отправки запросов асинхронно?

Comment: Сколько у вас ядер?

Comment: @senmai 8 ядер, но я специально выставил 1 потому что при 2 потоках golang использует блокировки и производительность падает, я сам замерял. У меня производительность упала более чем в 10 раз при 8 потоках.

Comment: На этом коде упала производительность? Как измеряли? Покажите код.